# Is there a way to stop MySQL Replication on the master?

Tags: mysql, replication

I want the master to stop replicating data to the slave. I know I can do that on the slave with `STOP SLAVE;`, but I wonder if there is a way to do it in the master.

One possible solution might be to change the `server_id` to 0, but in this case I'll have to restart mysql in the master for changes to take effect.

What I'm looking for is a statement like `STOP MASTER;`.

Comment: Hm, would denying connections to the IP the slave is located work?

Comment: you mean by changing replication user's pw or such?

Comment: Why do you want the master to stop replicating data to the slave?  Is it because you do not want to use replication any more, or are you trying to solve a different problem?  The best answer, and a safe answer, to your question cannot be given, without that information.

Comment: the slave is no longer reachable and i want to stop replication from the master so that when the slave is reachable again, replication is not continued.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There does not exist a `STOP MASTER;` command nor is there a manual mechanism from the Master to stop Replication. You would have to go to each Slave and run on of the following:

- `STOP SLAVE;` (Kills the IO Thread and SQL Thread)
- `STOP SLAVE IO_THREAD;` (Kills the IO Thread only)

Running either of these will get you the following:

- Clean Recording of the Replication Coordinates in `master.info`

  - Master_Log_File
  - Read_Master_Log_Pos
  - Relay_Master_Log_file
  - Exec_Master_Log_Pos

The IO Thread is what communicates with the Master. Killing the IO Thread on the Master Side using the `KILL` command would abort the IO Thread on each Slave. That could corrupt the Clean Recording of Replication Coordinates.

Comment: RolandoMySQLDBA I don't care if this comment does not follow stack over flow policies, but I liked to thank you for your dedication and great answers.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this online would be to revoke all `REPLICATION SLAVE` privileges on the master for any users who have it.

This offers the additional benefit of allowing you to be selective about which slaves you remove.

Once that's done, check for any existing replication sessions with `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and kill them off with the `KILL` command (these might drop off by themselves after you revoke the privileges, but I suspect this isn't the case).

You need to have in mind that, using this approach, the replication won't completely stop on slave, what will happen is that the `SLAVE IO_THREAD` won't be able to get new statements (queries) from master, but if you eventually have queries that you already get from master(these are saved on your relay log) but didn't execute yet (you can check if you have seconds behind master to see if it is the case), it won't prevent these queries to don't execute.

Comment: If you revoke privileges, make sure you also run an `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` to tell MySQL to reload the privilege table in memory.

Comment: You should rarely need to `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` unless you're modifying the permissions in the MySQL tables directly - if you drop permissions using REVOKE or DROP USER then the server will reload the grant tables automatically.

Comment: i'll give it a try later today

Comment: i tried it and actually replication continued on the slave, i had to issue `stop slave;` and `start slave`; for it to work!

Comment: on [MySQL Flush Doc Page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/flush.html) you can see that `REVOKE`, `DROP USER`, `DROP SERVER`, and `UNINSTALL PLUGIN` does not flush the privileges tables from memory. After execute any of this commands, you still need to run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`.

Comment: Actually, [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privilege-changes.html) states that _using ... GRANT, REVOKE, or SET PASSWORD, the server notices these changes and loads the grant tables into memory again immediately_. It's only a small amount of cached memory that's not released automatically.